# Cloud Functions Memory Allocation Impact

Tags: firebase, memory, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi everyone I'm using Firestore Cloud Functions and I have a very complex function that due to its heavy work sometimes give me TimedOut Error.
I was wondering If allocating more memory to the functions passing from `256MB` to `1GB` can really solve my problem and also makes the execution faster.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Please show your code. Otherwise your question is far too broad and theoretical for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a machine with more memory indeed also means that it has a faster CPU. So in addition to performance benefits you'll get from the available memory (which in the case where you use Cloud Firestore can be significant), you'll also get the performance gains of a faster CPU executing your code.

That said: there are many reasons why your code might be timing out. Without seeing a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we won't be able say much more than I said above.